# kotlin, how to put HashMap in Parcelable

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap, parcelable

In a class who implements Parcelable it has a HashMap member.

Saw Parcelable has 
`public final void readMap(Map outVal, ClassLoader loader)`,  but could not find a sample to use it.

If do it by flatten the map and write/read one by one accordingly, how to extract from the parcel in the constructor? (got error to build the map from the parcelable,  `cannot access buildTheMap() before constructor is called`)

```
class CachedData(val type: Int,
             val name: String,
             val details: HashMap<String, String) :
    Parcelable {

constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readInt(),
        parcel.readString(),

        // how to get the hashMap out of the parcel???
        buildTheMap(parcel)   //<=== cannot access buildTheMap() before constructor is called
)

fun buildTheMap(parcel: Parcel) :HashMap<String, String> {

    val size = parcel.readInt()
    val map = HashMap<String, String>()

    for (i in 1..size) {
        val key = parcel.readString()
        val value = parcel.readString()
        map[key] = value
    }
    return map
}

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeInt(type)
    parcel.writeString(name)

    // how to write the HashMap<String, String> to the parcel
    //parcel.???

    parcel.writeInt(details.size)
    for ((key, value) in details) {
        parcel.writeString(key)
        parcel.writeString(value)
    }
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object {
    @JvmField val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<CachedData> = object : Parcelable.Creator<CachedData>{
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): CachedData {
            return CachedData(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<CachedData?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for me a faced with the same problem. The working for me solution was:

```
public class JoustBattler extends Parcelable {

...

 private Map<String, Integer> battleWins;


 protected JoustBattler(Parcel in) {
        super(in);

        int battleWinsSize = in.readInt();
        this.battleWins = new HashMap<String, Integer>(battleWinsSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < battleWinsSize; i++) {
            String key = in.readString();
            Integer value = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
            this.battleWins.put(key, value);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);

        dest.writeInt(this.battleWins.size());
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : this.battleWins.entrySet()) {
            dest.writeString(entry.getKey());
            dest.writeValue(entry.getValue());
        }

    }
```

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: thanks @Serg!, plus 1 for suggesting not use the primary constructor syntax.  It works.  Hoping if there is other sample of using the built in `final void readMap(Map outVal, ClassLoader loader)`

Answer (score 5):

Still hope some to share how to use the readMap().

Here is the kotlin version to flatten the map, for reference.

```
class CachedData :
    Parcelable {

var type: Int = 0
var name: String = ""
var details: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()

constructor (type: Int,
             name: String,
             details: HashMap<String, String>) {
    this.type = type
    this.name = name
    this.details = details
}

constructor(parcel: Parcel) {
    this.type = parcel.readInt()
    this.name = parcel.readString()
    this.details = buildTheMap(parcel)
}

fun buildTheMap(parcel: Parcel): HashMap<String, String> {

    val size = parcel.readInt()
    val map = HashMap<String, String>(size)

    for (i in 1..size) {
        val key = parcel.readString()
        val value = parcel.readString()
        map[key] = value
    }
    return map
}

fun writeToMap(parcel: Parcel) {
    parcel.writeInt(details.size)
    for ((key, value) in details) {
        parcel.writeString(key)
        parcel.writeString(value)
    }
}

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeInt(type)
    parcel.writeString(name)
    writeToMap(parcel)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object {
    @JvmField
    val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<CachedData> = object : Parcelable.Creator<CachedData> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): CachedData {
            return CachedData(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<CachedData?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`@Parcelize`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#parcelable-implementations-generator) and just write

```
@Parcelize
class CachedData(val type: Int, val name: String, val details: HashMap<String, String>) : Parcelable
```

It has built-in support for `HashMap` (and other collection types).

Comment: Awesome! Note that you will need to `plugins {id 'kotlin-parcelize'}` to your module `build.gradle` for it to work.