# kotlin, how to make a hashMap parcelable

Tags: android, kotlin, onsaveinstancestate

Having a variable is hashMap`<IntRange, String>`, and need to put in bundle as parcelable to be saved and restored in onSaveStateInstance()/onCreateView() :

```
val map: HashMap<IntRange, String>? = hashMapOf(IntRange(0, 4) to "x", IntRange(5, -1) to "y")
```

and do

```
//saving:
outState.putParcelable("saved_map", map)

...
//retrieving: 
val map = bundle.getParcelable("saved_map")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449891/kotlin-how-to-put-hashmap-in-parcelable

Comment: right, but that needs a wrap class derived from Parcelable. Is there a simpler way to jus put the map in the bundle?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to use Serializable instead, see here (it's Java but you can easily convert to Kotlin): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452859/android-hashmap-in-bundle

Comment: @DanielNugent, good idea - hashMap is a serializable, thx! If you could put it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Is `IntRange` serializable, though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a wrapper class nonetheless, just because it's much simpler in Kotlin than in Java. `@Parcelize` [supports `HashMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html), the problem is that it doesn't support `IntRange` (or at least it isn't listed). But based on the example there, it seems this should work:

```
object IntRangeParceler : Parceler<IntRange> {
    override fun create(parcel: Parcel) = IntRange(parcel.readInt(), parcel.readInt())

    override fun IntRange.write(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeInt(value, start)
        parcel.writeInt(value, endInclusive)
    }
}

@Parcelize
@TypeParceler<IntRange, IntRangeParceler>()
class IntRangeStringMap(val value: HashMap<IntRange, String>)
```

and your calls become

```
outState.putParcelable("saved_map", IntRangeStringMap(map))
val map = bundle.getParcelable("saved_map").value
```

You can even get it looking the way you want by adding extension functions.

Comment: thx! but if change to ArrayList<Pair<IntRange, String>> (need keep the order), crash:

Parcelable IOException writing serializable object (name = kotlin.Pair)
      at com.test.IntRangeStringMap.writeToParcel(TestIntRangStringMap.kt)
--- --- ---
@Parcelize
@TypeParceler<IntRange, IntRangeParceler>()
class IntRangeStringMap(val value: HashMap<IntRange, String>) : Parcelable
== === ===
val rangeToSpaceMap: ArrayList<Pair<IntRange, String>>? = arrayListOf(Pair(IntRange(1, 5), “X”),Pair(IntRange(6, -1), “y”)
=== argument.putParcelable(“parelable_map”,IntRangeStringMap(rangeToSpaceMap!!))

Comment: You can use `LinkedHashMap` to keep the order.

Answer (score 0):

based on @Alexey Romanov's answer, got a working version

I changed to making a parcelable `ArrayList<Pair<IntRange, String>>`

```
object IntRangeParceler : Parceler<IntRange> {
    override fun create(parcel: Parcel) = IntRange(parcel.readInt(), parcel.readInt())

    override fun IntRange.write(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeInt(first)
        parcel.writeInt(last)
    }
}

object PairParceler : Parceler<Pair<IntRange, String>> {
    override fun create(parcel: Parcel): Pair<IntRange, String> =
        Pair(IntRange(parcel.readInt(), parcel.readInt()), parcel.readString())

    override fun Pair<IntRange, String>.write(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeInt(first.first)
        parcel.writeInt(first.last)
        parcel.writeString(second)
    }
}

@Parcelize
@TypeParceler<IntRange, IntRangeParceler>()
@TypeParceler<Pair<IntRange, String>, PairParceler>()
class IntRangeStringMap(val value:  ArrayList<Pair<IntRange, String>>) : Parcelable
```